# how to select latest item on top of the list and rest of the item in sorted order

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, listbox

I am creating a listbox using Winform and C#. I am adding the items in tabels and the list of items is loading from two tabels in the listbox according to the creationdate using the below query.

```
SELECT Boxname, CreationDate FROM tabe1 

 UNION  

 SELECT TrashBoxName, CreationDate FROM table2  

 order by CreationDate DESC
```

But i want to select the newly added item on top of listbox and rest of items in sorted order.

For Example items like 1,7,3,9 when i add 5 it will come on top like 5 1 3 7 9 and rest of the item will sort

Thanks

Comment: when you add item which table you insert into ?

Comment: How you find the item 5 as newly added. Is the CreationDate varies?

Comment: How many tables you are using. why you mention table1 and table2?

Comment: if box name is PKS it will go to tabe2 and rest of the box will go to table 1

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to change your first query to get the ones you want on top, then union the second query as you want the rest of the list. So it'll be something like:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 Boxname, CreationDate, 1 as newOrder FROM tabe1
 UNION  
 SELECT TrashBoxName, CreationDate, 2 FROM table2  
 ORDER BY newOrder ASC, CreationDate DESC
```

Alternatively you might want a where clause in your first query to get all new records:

```
 SELECT Boxname, CreationDate, 1 as newOrder FROM tabe1
 WHERE [...your condition to find the data you want at the top...]
 UNION
 SELECT TrashBoxName, CreationDate, 2 FROM table2
 ORDER BY newOrder ASC, CreationDate DESC
```

Comment: it is giving the error- Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
and what is this newrecord?

Comment: The condition `[newRecord] = true` should be replaced with a condition to determine the values you want at the top of your select box. Is there some way you can identify those records, like having a column called newRecord that's set to true? I'll update my anwer to show you better what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick-

```
(
    select top 1 Boxname,CreationDate from table1 order by CreationDate desc
)
union
(
    select BoxName, CreationDate from table2  order by CreationDate asc
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to order the items on your wish.

```
SELECT Boxname as Boxname, CreationDate, 1 AS RowID FROM tabe1 
UNION  
SELECT TrashBoxName as Boxname, CreationDate, 1 + Row_number() 
    OVER(ORDER BY CreationDate ASC) AS RowID FROM table2  
ORDER BY RowID ASC
```

I added new column **RowID**. RowID for new item is 1 and others are 2,3,4...
So, we can order the data based on RowID.

Comment: what is this heatnumber?

Comment: sorry, it is CreationDate. Kindly delete your command. I changed the answer.